# Android 4.2.2+ Secure USB debugging OK screen reinstatement

Tags: android, eclipse, nexus-7, usb-debugging

I was debugging a new app on a Nexus 7 and all was OK.  About 1 month ago, I think my old Nexus 7 was upgraded to Android 4.3.  I think it offered me a screen entitled "Allow USB debugging?", but I was busy and hit cancel to get it off my screen.  I believe that's the reason Eclipse can no longer access my Nexus 7.  Other tablets (Asus TF700 and a Trio) are working.  I bought new cables and searched the web to get another chance at the screen which allowed USB debugging from my main computer.  On my laptop, I payed attention to the "Allow USB debugging" window, and the Nexus 7 works there.  I have the latest loads, including Android Debug Bridge Version 1.0.31. ">adb devices" yields "List of devices attached" then nothing.

How do I get a second chance to approve USB debugging between my Nexus 7 and my main Win 8 desktop?

Here's an Eclipse console message: "Failed to find an AVD compatible with target 'Android 4.4'."

Some relevant articles include:

http://nelenkov.blogspot.com/2013/02/secure-usb-debugging-in-android-422.html

http://www.androidpolice.com/2013/02/12/new-android-4-2-2-feature-usb-debug-whitelist-prevents-adb-savvy-thieves-from-stealing-your-data-in-some-situations/

Comment: Unplug the Nexus from your computer and replug it in. Make sure you are using camera (PTP) mode, and enabled USB Debugging in Developer Options.

Comment: Using the PTP mode did the trick of allowing a USB connection to my Nexus 7.  Thank you very, very much!  I had been working on this problem for several days/weeks, including lots of repluging.  USB Debugging was enabled long ago.

Comment: I added my comment as an answer.

Comment: Since my comment answered your question, you can mark my answer as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, unplug and replug the Nexus from your computer. Then, double check that you are using Camera (PTP) USB mode. If you do not have this mode enabled, ADB will not recognize your device. Also, double check that USB Debugging is enabled in Developer Options.